# Getting 404 Not Found, while calling JAX-RS Rest API method

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jax-rs, http-status-code-404

I am trying to call **REST API** method (method been declared without **@Path** annotation).

Resource path for this API has been loaded in server start up itself using **BaseRestServer.rootPath**.

I expect that this API will get called by default, as there are no other apis available to process the request.

But when i call this api, I am getting '404 Not Found' as response.

code is something like, as given below,

```
**@Path("")**
public class JobResource{

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/job")
    @Produces("application/job")
    public Response postJob(
            @Context HttpServletRequest hRequest, Job job){
    }

}
```

resource path has been defined in the server file itself, as given below

```
BaseRestServer.rootPath = "/shared/job/"+companyName.
```

**Reason on why i have not used resource path in the class is, that it allows only constant value inside @Path annotation.
But in my case, companyName value changes dynamically**

When I pass this dynamic value inside `@Path("/shared/job/"+companyName)`, i am getting compilation error as '**The Value for annotation attribute Path.value must be a constant expression**'

Comment: You'd expect the path to be `"/"` not `""` the dynamic company name looks like a `path param` - `/{companyName}`

Comment: https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2079